# How i should get the data of notification push if my app run?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Hi first of all thank you for the answer and sorry for my bad english. How i can get information of notification push?
I send the information with the console of google.
This is my method onCreate of my main class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });


    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        String Name = null;

        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
            if (key.equals("Name")) {
                Log.d("Jack", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
                Name = (String) value;
            }

        }
}
```

pd: i try copy the same code in the method onPause but didn't work

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure what's being asked here. You already have a code for getting the data from intent extras. Are you getting an error of some sort?

Comment: Now i solved the problem i read the post thank you for the answers